# refering something as "non-linear" when there is no underlying linear structure

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, monoid, nonlinear-analysis, geometric-functional-analysis

Can I talk about a non-linear shape functional. I understand a shape functional $J$ as some mapping that takes a shape and returns a real (or complex) value.

I would like to talk about a non-linear shape functional as one that does not fulfill:

$$
J\left(A\cup B\right)=J\left(A\right)+J\left(B\right)
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of the set $\Omega$.

The problem here is that, denoting $\mathcal{P}\left(\Omega\right)$ as the power set of $\Omega$ (i.e. the collection of its subsets), $\left(\mathcal{P}\left(\Omega\right),\cup\right)$ only has monoid structure, but not a vector space structure.

So really what i'm saying is that $J:\mathcal{P}\left(\Omega\right)\to\mathbb{R}$ does not conserve the monoid structure. However I always hear people saying "it's not linear" so I would like to know it it makes any sense to refer it like that, of if I'm missing something...

If someone can point me to some useful reference that would be also fine.

Comment: Maybe say it's not additive, [since "additive" is used in this way for measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Additivity).

Comment: I guess then that if people say "it's non-linear" is because, even if you could define a linear structure in both domain and image, if the mapping is not additive it won't be linear. So I think it is an abuse of the term.

Comment: Plus signs were originally used to denote unions of sets (roughly first third to around first half of the 1900s), and the word "addition" was also used for the union operation, so it wasn't originally an abuse of the term. Indeed, the phrase ["additive set function"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22additive+set+function%22) was pretty much universally used in abstract measure theory literature in the first half of the 1900s, and the phrase is still widely used.

Comment: I was trying to say that using the term "non-linear" in this situation, were there is no linear structure os an abuse of the term.